# Wordpress Setting Featured Image Size and Adding link to featured image and Title

Tags: arrays, wordpress, wordpress-featured-image

I've created a filterable portfolio in wordpress followindg a quicksand tutorial I found.

Everything is working but the author did not **link the featured image in the page template nor set the thumbnail size for the post type**. I want the thumbnail size to be `280px x 180px`.

Here is the code: (Edited working code below)

```
<ul class="portfolio-grid">
        <?php


        $pfportfolio = new WP_Query( 'post_type=portfolio' );


        while ( $pfportfolio->have_posts() ) : $pfportfolio->the_post();?>


        <?php
            echo '<li data-id="post-'.get_the_ID().'" data-type="'.$terms_as_text = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'pftype', '', ' ', '' ) ).'">';
            ?>
            <div class="item">
                        <div class="view third-effect">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'kubrick'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'homepage-thumb' ); ?></a>
            <?php

            ?>
            <div class="mask">
                            </div>
            <div class="item-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'kubrick'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <?php

            echo '</li>';
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a new image size in your functions file ( see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size ) then change this line to add the new image size id instead of 'home-feat'.

```
the_post_thumbnail('home-feat');
```

(for example, too )

```
the_post_thumbnail('new-image-size');
```

Comment: Thanks Ollie! That fixed the image sizing issue. Do you know how to link the featured image and title using the code above?

Comment: Yea you'll need to wrap the post thumbnail in a <a> tag with the href as follows:
`<a href="<?php the_title(); ?>`
It will mean you have to close PHP and reopen it again before and after the link.